# Alloy: Int meaning of field

Tags: alloy

i saw the following Alloy definition:

one sig Number { i:Int[3]}

//what does Int[3] mean. I mean what is the meaning of the above field 'i'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `i` is a relation between the singleton set `Number` and the singleton subset of `Int` with the atom `3`. In object notation it's like `Number.i = 3`